# Manually clearing HHVM cache

Tags: php, hhvm

I am using hhvm version 3.0.1 on ubuntu 13.10, with JIT enabled, in fastcgi mode and nginx webserver. 
 I need to  know how to clear cache so that i can see the code change immediately...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any cache that you need to clear. Editing a file then reloading the page should show your changes. There is an inotify hook to watch for changed files which will recompile that file on reload.

Comment: i was using 3.5 in dev. in production 3.6.1 and now wordpress won't work "unexpected T_ELSE in line 1 of file. but there is no else in line 1 of the file. how can i delete the jit cache and try to recompile it. it has to be an error

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue - hh_client complained about not existing lines (v3.11.1). 
Rebooting my machine helped.

Answer (score 0):

Just kill these processes from the shell:

```sh
pkill hh_server
pkill hh_client
```